# Custom properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a requirement from a client to give them the option to add custom fields to a program i am going to write for them. The custom fields will be on a per/poco basis. What is the best way of handling custom properties like this. I am going to use SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC4.

Just need a starting point..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way we handle this where I work is storing the information in a database table. We store the field name, the value, and some identifier for which object it belongs to. Sometimes we have an additional table stores the specific list of available values.

When it's pulled out of the db, we place it in a dictionary list. If you set up some conventions then it's not too bad building validation for the fields. I.E. any field name with "phone" in the name gets validated as a phone number.